# How to run Kotlin application in Gradle task and not wait exit code to success finish task?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build

I need to run Kotlin BackEnd application in Gradle task and after it run auto tests application.
So I created 2 tasks: runApp and runAutoTests (runAutoTests dependsOn runApp). But runApp do not return exit code, because it is not finish(It is Spring application). And runAutoTests never start.

```
val runApp by tasks.registering(JavaExec::class) {
    mainClass = "myApp"
}

val runAutoTests by tasks.registering(YarnTask::class) {
    dependsOn("runApp")
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to wait until my runApp is start and then run another task (Without waiting exit code)?

Comment: I was able to achieve this by using this plugin:
https://github.com/psxpaul/gradle-execfork-plugin, just be aware of this issue: https://github.com/psxpaul/gradle-execfork-plugin/issues/25